# Remove login form (and registration) on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, user-registration

I trying to remove login and registration at checkout from woocommerce plugin in wordpress

i tried guest checkout but this not working
i tried this code

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', $checkout );

if ( ! $checkout->is_registration_enabled() && $checkout->is_registration_required() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_checkout_must_be_logged_in_message', __( 'You must be logged in to checkout.', 'woocommerce' ) ) );
return;
}
```

When I commented if condition then it opens checkout form but when I clicked place order it gives me this error:

> *"Create account password is a required field. Account username is a required field."*

What I am doing wrong? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

To remove login form from Woocommerce checkout use:

```
// Remove login form from checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'remove_checkout_login_form', 4 );
function remove_checkout_login_form(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
}
```

To remove Registration from Woocommerce checkout simply use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_registration_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

Both snippets goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks a lot @loictheaztec ! I have used this to unhook it at the top and hook it onto a custom hook within the checkout FORM. However, once you place it into the <form> element on the checkout page, the sliding functionality, doesn't work anymore, i.e. it's always collapsed and the login fields are always visible. Is there a way to retain the sliding / opening effect?